# JavaFX Separator depend not on the Width of the Class

Tags: properties, javafx, width, separator

i would like to get a Separator, which changes his Size with the Size of the Mother-Component.
In my Example, i have a JavaFX Popup and there i add a VBox. To this VBox i add a HBox. And this HBox has a Label, a Speparator and a Button.
Now i would like to have that the Button is on the Right End and the Label is on the Left End of the HBox. I think i have to use a Separator between these components to get the Space.

How can i handle it...

I made something like this, but it does not work.

```
// Box for the Headline
    HBox headLine = new HBox();
    headLine.setPadding(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));

    // Label with the HeadLine Description in
    final Label heading = new Label(headLineText);
    heading.getStyleClass().addAll("popup-label-name");

    // Close Button
    close = new Button("X");
    close.setVisible(false);
    closeButtonHandler();

    // Creates an invisble Separator1
    Separator sep = new Separator(Orientation.HORIZONTAL);
    sep.setVisible(false);
    sep.widthProperty().add(m_container.widthProperty().get());

    close.getStyleClass().addAll("popup-button", "popup-button-color");

    // Adds to the Headline the Data
    headLine.getChildren().addAll(heading, sep, close);
```

The Variable m_container is the VBox! How can i handle it?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Do you just want blank space? Or a visible separator?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way (if not using a different container like AnchorPane) is to insert an invisible, but expandible 'space' object:

```
void testLabelSpace(HBox box) {        
    Text first = new Text("first");
    Text second = new Text("second");

    Node space = new HBox();      
    HBox.setHgrow(space, Priority.ALWAYS);

    box.getChildren().addAll(first, space, second);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you just want blank space between the label and the button. Just tell the `Label` always to grow horizontally, and set its maximum width to allow it to grow to any size:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class HBoxExample extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        HBox hbox = new HBox();
        Label label = new Label("Label");
        Button button = new Button("Button");
        HBox.setHgrow(label, Priority.ALWAYS);
        label.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        hbox.getChildren().addAll(label, button);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(hbox, 350, 75));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```